# How to disable snapping for knife project?

Tags: snapping, knife-tool

I am trying to cut two different meshes A and B with the same polyline P so that I can join A and B afterwards with no holes or anomalies. I am using the knife project tool and this works quite well.

The problem: the knife project seems to have vertex snapping enabled. Whenever P is too close to any vertex of A or B the new inserted vertex snaps to those vertices. However, the vertices of A and B do not lie at the same positions.
Thus, it often happens that-using the same polyline for the projection-the A and B do not fit perfectly due to holes in the joint mesh.

Is there any (hidden) parameter or other possibility to disable this snapping behavior in the knife projection? Otherwise, I need to implement the same functionality by myself just because of the snapping... and I do not want to do that :-D

Edit: it seems there is not only a vertex snapping but a general inaccuracy. I tried to illustrate the problem with the following images.

The polyline (vertices in orange) and one of the meshs:
[image]

After applying the knife project tool (polyline in orange):
[image]

Hiding the polyline:
[image]

Comment: I'm having some difficulty [reproducing this](https://imgur.com/a/XNNfo2h) .. can you share an example file on pasteall.org/blend ? Possibilities.. projection, automerge.. floating-point error... or I'm wrong..

Comment: I am going to share an example in a minute. But... is the accuracy of the knife project tool depending on the current zoom level? I got different results when calling the tool in different zoom levels...

Comment: Could be.. floating point? ..  Stupid question, but have to ask, sorry .. you _are_ in an orthographic view?

Comment: Yes, I'm in orthographic top view. I already thought about the floating point problem since you mentioned it in your previous comment. However, if I zoom in until the background grid is in cm then the knife projection is pretty accurate. So, I guess, the zoom dependency is built-in...

Comment: Clipping range? Although.. Camera Z should be chucked out, and have nothing to do with it, really.

Comment: Here is the example blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/675cef8212424ed6a796556a0d7fc0fd

Comment: Sorry for delay, trying to chase down the code.. can anybody find it?  It's odd that the error is so consistent. I think it's probably f.p. error, and it's got a lot to do with the short length of the edges.. based only on the assumption 1. Calculation of vx locations in projection space.. 2. Parametric expression of edge between them. 3. Calc. Line-line intersection.

Comment: In fact, my initial questions leads into a wrong direction. As we found out in the meantime, there is no snapping which could be deactivated but there is another fact that results in different calculations on different zoom settings.